# Prior art for US2020233384A1 which applied reinforcement learning to wind turbines

Tags: prior-art-request, prior-art, us202023338

A patent, [US2020233384A1](https://worldwide.espacenet.com/patent/search/family/071609937/publication/US2020233384A1?q=US2020233384A1), has been filed which applies reinforcement learning to increase power from a wind turbine. It's ancestor is a Japanese patent JP2019006968A·2019-01-18.

This was filed in January 2019. I believe there is extensive prior art to the actual claims, which are very broad, in the academic literature. For example:

https://content.iospress.com/articles/integrated-computer-aided-engineering/ica531

or

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7081385

or

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7370922

How can I bring this to the examiners attention?

Comment: link to application that worked for me https://worldwide.espacenet.com/patent/search/family/071609937/publication/US2020233384A1?q=num%20%3D%20%222020%2F0233384%22

Comment: Just to be clear, this is an application, not yet a patent.

Comment: It would be helpful to tag this with us202023338.  Adding the tag for the publication will make this findable by the Examiner through Google Patents.  I can't do that because I don't have enough reputation on Ask Patents Stack Exchange.

Comment: @EAKretzmer, done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The USPTO has a  third-party issuance document submission process that was created by the AIA law. This was an important reason for Ask Patents to exist in its earlier days.  During a defined window anyone can submit documents that the examiner is obliged to consider. It can be done anonymously, if you like.

The window starts when the application is published and ends -

> A third-party preissuance submission statutorily must be made in a patent application before the earlier of:  (a) the date a notice of allowance under 35 U.S.C. 151 is given or mailed in the application; or (b) the later of (i) six months after the date on which the application is first published under 35 U.S.C. 122 by the Office, or (ii) the date of the first rejection under 35 U.S.C. 132 of any claim by the examiner during the examination of the application.

You can look the application up in [USPTO Public PAIR](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) to see the current status and check for the events that close the window. *As of 7/7/2020 it has not yet been assigned to an examiner so you are well in the window.*

[This link](https://www.uspto.gov/patent/initiatives/third-party-preissuance-submissions) takes you to the place to fill out the forms and upload your documents.

Comment: Thanks, how do I find this application in USPTO Public Pair? I can't seem to find it using the publication number, what do I need to search for?

Comment: Public PAIR has an unforgiving interface. Note the radio buttons default to entering an application #, not a publication number. In publication number do not enter US or suffix like A1. No commas. Alternatively the application # is 16/733880